# How to resolve Notice: Undefined variable: form ...?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, render

when I have created my page indexSuccess.php, i used an instruction like :

```
    <?php echo $form['titre']->render();?>
```

it gives me an error when executing like :

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: form in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\apps\frontend\modules\addAnnonce\templates\indexSuccess.php on line 84

    Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\apps\frontend\modules\addAnnonce\templates\indexSuccess.php on line 84
```

what can I doas solution for that problem?

Comment: Did you assign the form to the template as `$form` in your action: `$this->form = new WhateverClassForm();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you auto-generate a doctrine model, the form is created as a partial and embedded in the new & edit templates. If you check your newSuccess, createSuccess, editSuccess, updateSuccess actions, you will find the assignment of the form variable as mentioned by prodigitalson, so this error wont appear there.

However, the form is not automatically made available on indexSuccess, as that page by naming convention is supposed to be used for listing out the objects. Breaking the convention might lead to some confusion later.

One more tip: if you want to create a screen similar to the symfony admin backend, where you list all objects along with a form to add/edit objects, you can use generator.yml to automatically generate your views. Be sure to include css,js&images from web/sf folder in the symfony directory

Answer (score 0):

So, I found what I'm searching for. I forgot to add

```
  $this->form = new addAnnonceForm();
```

in my executeIndex(action)

thx :)